# Corretc Excel VBA Macro to Return the values as text and as date

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help. I have a macro to arrange some datas as follows:

```
    Sub Espelho_OM()

Dim Linha As Integer
Dim Data_Vencimento As String
Dim N1 As String
Dim N2 As String
Dim N3 As String
Dim N4 As String
Dim N5 As String
Dim N6 As String
Dim N7 As String
Dim N8 As Double
Dim i As Integer

 Sheets(2).Cells.Clear

 Sheets(1).Select

  Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Select
  Linha = ActiveCell.Row - 1

   For i = 1 To Linha
     N1 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1)
     N2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2)
     N3 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3)
     N4 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 4)
     N5 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 5)
     N6 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 6)
     N7 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 7)
     N8 = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 8)
     Sheets(2).Cells(1 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N1
     Sheets(2).Cells(2 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N2
     Sheets(2).Cells(4 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N3
     Sheets(2).Cells(5 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N4
     Sheets(2).Cells(6 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N5
     Sheets(2).Cells(7 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N6
     Sheets(2).Cells(8 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N7
     Sheets(2).Cells(10 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = N8




Next

  Sheets(2).Select

End Sub
```

I need the colums N5 and N5 to record the data in the format ddmmyy, and N1 to record the data exactly as it is on the sheets(1) (00050661), is this possible?

Today the columns nn5 and n6 is coming dd/mm/yy and the column N1 is coming 50661 taking off the zeros from the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use range.numberformat like this:

```
Sheets(2).Cells(6 + (i - 1) * 38, 1).numberformat = "ddmmyy"
```

with the other the number format will be the number of digits desired in zeros "00000000"

you could also try:

```
Sheets(2).Cells(6 + (i - 1) * 38, 1) = "'" & N5
```

add "'" & through out it will force the numbers to remain strings.

Comment: First thanks for the quick answer. It did not work but I think I was not clear on the question. For example, colum N5 in the sheets(1) has the following data 01/03/2015 when I run the macro I want this data to become 010315. The same with the N1, the data is 00050667 when I run it becomes 50667 and I want to keep 00050667. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MarcosViniciusdosSantos is there a reason you are using a variable as the middle man?  Can you not simply equate the two cells directly?

Comment: I will use this to paste on a screen in an ERP, that is why the format is so important otherwise the system will point as error.

Comment: @MarcosViniciusdosSantos I added something else to try.

Comment: Also the data is on several columns, I need the to be in only one column to make the copy and paste on the system.

Comment: @MarcosViniciusdosSantos you are welcome. feel free to mark it as the correct answer.