# Run time error 13 Type Mismatch in program module which ran successfully earlier

Tags: excel, vba

Sample data:

```
0votes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382401/autohide-multiple-rows-in-excel/32383360#32383360
vbaexcel
answered Sep 3, 2015 at 18:53
0votes
Accepted
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273121/corretc-excel-vba-macro-to-return-the-values-as-text-and-as-date/32273219#32273219  'clickable format
vbaexcel
answered Aug 28, 2015 at 14:18
```

I want to insert a row between votes and url line if the answer is not accepted and url immediately follows votes line with a purpose to make grouping of 5 rows for ultimately transposing data in a single row.

This is my code:

```
Sub insertrow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*vote*" And (Cells(i + 1, "A").Value) <> "Accepted" Then
        Cells(i + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I am getting Run time error 13 Type mismatch on the following line although this program ran successfully yesterday night for similar data.

```
If (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*vote*" And (Cells(i + 1, "A").Value) <> "Accepted"
```

Any help will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Why don't you use [instr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) instead? Remember that in these kind of scenarios is better to either lcase or ucase the string. In addition, whenever you get the "type mismatch" error in this context, most likely there is an error on the cell, however, you should try to use [Cstr](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cstr.php) too

Comment: You should qualify all `Cells` (tell VBA which worksheet you want to use). As you are already using a variable for your worksheet: Either use a `With ws` - statement and add a dot to the left of cells: `.Cells(i, "A")`, or  write `ws.Cells(i, "A")`. And check with the debugger the content of the cells when the error occurs

Comment: @FunThomas Your suggestion helped me to locate erring data by dubugging the contents of the cell when th error occurs and  also associating sheet using `With ws` It has solved the problem fully. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sgdva your suggestion is ok if the basic data is faultless. If the base data is faulty then without identifying the problem garbage in will be garbage out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick test with the data and the code you provided and had no issues. However, there is a problem with the code: Although you assign a specific sheet to a variable, you continue to work with the *ActiveSheet*. It is likely that this sheet is not the sheet with your sample data and may contain data that lead to the type mismatch error.

When programming VBA in Excel, you should always qualify exactly on which worksheet you want to work. One way is to use a `With`-statement. Take care that before *every* instance of `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` and `Columns` you add a dot - that tells VBA you are referring to the object of the `With`-statement.

```
Sub insertrow()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Dim Last As Long, i As Long
        Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            If (.Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*vote*" _
            And (.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value) <> "Accepted" Then
                .Cells(i + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Or, if you like that better:

```
Sub insertrow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 
    
    Dim Last As Long, i As Long
    Last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (ws.Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*vote*" _
        And (ws.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value) <> "Accepted" Then
            ws.Cells(i + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Errors like type mismatch usually can be revealed rather easy by checking the related data (in this case content of 2 cells) with the debugger.